# Every user have your own listed data when he/she will login by his/her credential

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jsp

In my project N- number of User is available. Every user can do insert update deleted list of data. every users have different different data. suppose one user have 10 record another user have 20 record and 3rd user have 15 record etc.

I have try to multiple user can register and login to my application with first user in side first user account i have inserted 10 record and display then logout. again i will login with different user then that same data will be display which is inserted by previous user. So my problem is how to maintain every user data with your own account i am beginner in spring-boot with hibernate, jsp.

1.Usercontroller.java

```
package com.rajesh.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.rajesh.model.User;
import com.rajesh.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String Home(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
    @PostMapping("/user/register")
    public String registerNewUser(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("userRegister")@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
            model.addAttribute("msgEmail", "your email is already registered");
            logger.info("your email Id is already registered");
            System.out.println("your email is already registered");
            return "home";
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            model.addAttribute("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
            logger.info("User has been registered successfully");
            System.out.println("User has been registered successfully");
            return "home";
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/login") 
    public String doLogin(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("command")User user, HttpSession session) {

        if(userService.loginUser(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
            session.setAttribute("email",user.getEmail());
            session.setAttribute("user_id", user.getId());
            model.addAttribute("sucessLogin", "You are login sucessfully");
            logger.info("You are login sucessfully",user.getEmail());
            System.out.println("You are login sucessfully "+ user.getEmail());
            return "redirect:userdashboard";
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Email/Password");
            logger.error("Invalid Email/Password");
            model.put("failed", "Invalid Email/Password");
            return "home";
        }       
    }
    @PostMapping("/user/checkstatus")
    @ResponseBody
    public Integer checkUserStatus(String email, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("command")User user, HttpSession session) {
            int userStatus = userService.isActiveUserStatus(email);
            System.out.println(userStatus);
            if(userStatus != 0) {
                System.out.println(userStatus);
                return userStatus;
            }else {
                System.out.println(userStatus);
                return userStatus;
            }
    }
    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String doLogout(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("command")User user, HttpSession session) {
        session.removeAttribute("email");
        logger.info("you are logout successfully");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

2. User.java

```
package com.rajesh.model;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
/**
 * @author Rajesh Bhushan
 */
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="shopname")
    @Length(min = 3, message = "*Your shopname must have at least 3 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an shopname")
    private String shopname;

    @Column(name="name")
    @Length(min = 3, message = "*Your name must have at least 3 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address")
    @Length(min = 3, message = "*Your address must have at least 3 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="mobile")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an address")
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password") 
    private String password;

    @Column(name="active")
    private int active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getShopname() {
        return shopname;
    }
    public void setShopname(String shopname) {
        this.shopname = shopname;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

3. UserRepository.java

```
package com.rajesh.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.rajesh.model.User;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByEmail(String email);
    @Query("from User as u where u.email=:email and u.password=:password")
    public User loginUser(String email,String password);
    @Query("select active from User as u where u.email=:email")
    public Integer isActiveUserStatus(String email);
}
```

4.UserService.java

```
package com.rajesh.service;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.rajesh.model.Role;
import com.rajesh.model.User;
import com.rajesh.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.rajesh.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        user.setShopname(user.getShopname());
        user.setName(user.getName());
        user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        user.setMobile(user.getMobile());
        user.setAddress(user.getAddress());
        user.setActive(0);
        user.setCreatedBy(user.getName());
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        user.setUpdatedBy(user.getName());
        user.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

        Role userRole  = roleRepository.findByRole("USER");
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public User loginUser(String email,String password) {
        return userRepository.loginUser(email, password);
    }
    public Integer isActiveUserStatus(String email) {
        Integer activeStatus =  userRepository.isActiveUserStatus(email);
        return activeStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: First you should start with Table Structure. 
[\n] ex : one {user} can have many {item}s, so we create table {user_item} that cantain id of table {user} and {item} related to each other.

[\n] When we call list item(/api/list) it should use {user} id to retrieve list item of that user from table {item}, {user_item} with related {user}&{item} id.

Comment: but inside user Account much more table is there in every table i want to set userId column in that all tables

Comment: Simply think that if your tables is many-to-many or one-to-many relationship, need to create third table to map its id. otherwise one-to-one, we just add user-id to that table and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a userid column on data table. So when listing data get datas according to userid.

Comment: but i have much more add update delete form in the user account